# My list in python is for some reason being overwritten with [' ']

Tags: python, list, csv, index-error

I have a python program that reads a list of birthdays from a csv file and determines if any of them are today. The code is supposed to read in each line, split the input, and assign each component into the appropriate variable. This is the code:

```
# checks birthday list for any birthdays
        for entry in birthday_list:
            string = birthday_list.readline()
            string = string[:-1]
            info = string.split(',')
            print(info)
            name = info[0]
            birth_day = int(info[1])
            birth_month = int(info[2])
            birth_year = int(info[3])
            # sends message
            if (day == birth_day and month == birth_month):
                age = year - birth_year
                wish_string = 'Happy ' + str(age) + determine_ordinal(age) + ' birthday, ' + name + '!\nhttps://imgur.com/a/G3wEPyg'
                await channel.send(wish_string)
        birthday_list.close()
```

The real output has personal info, but this is what it looks like:

```
['Ponkachu', '7', '8', '2020']
['']
```

I get an IndexError at the line that assigns birth_day to int(info[1])

print(string) prints "Ponkachu,7,8,2020"

If I change print(info) to print(info[1]), it gives me "7" and then an IndexError

If I change it to print(len(info)), I get this:

```
4

1
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. What's happening to info? Why is it suddenly changing?

Edit: I just checked the csv file. "Ponkachu,7,8,2020" is actually the second line, so it's for some reason skipping over the first line.

Edit 2: it turns out entry was being set to the input from the first line. This code works as intended:

```
for entry in birthday_list:
            info = entry.split(',')
            info[3] = info[3][:-1]
            name = info[0]
            birth_day = int(info[1])
            birth_month = int(info[2])
            birth_year = int(info[3])
            # sends message
            if (day == birth_day and month == birth_month):
                age = year - birth_year
                wish_string = 'Happy ' + str(age) + determine_ordinal(age) + ' birthday, ' + name + '!\nhttps://imgur.com/a/G3wEPyg'
                await channel.send(wish_string)
        birthday_list.close()
```

Comment: check if your input have any blanks.

Comment: It's also very possible that the last line of the file is empty. That's very common, you should make your code robust against that. (Also, check python's `csv` module)

Comment: @KarthikRadhakrishnan I just checked the csv file. "Ponkachu,7,8,2020" is actually the second line, so it's for some reason skipping over the first line.

Comment: Your loop is putting the first line into `entry`. Then you put the next line into `string`. Right?

Comment: Replace the personal information with dummy data and share the csv and the code

Comment: @jpf you were right. I fixed it by just using entry instead. Python isn't my first language, I'm used to reading/writing files in C.

Answer (score 0):

The iteration already reads a line from the file; calling `readline` gets the *next* line (ignoring the dangers of mixing iteration and `readline` due to the iterator's internal buffering).

```
    for entry in birthday_list:
        info = entry.rstrip('\n').split(',')
        print(info)
        name = info[0]
        birth_day = int(info[1])
        birth_month = int(info[2])
        birth_year = int(info[3])
        # sends message
        if day == birth_day and month == birth_month:
            age = year - birth_year
            wish_string = f'Happy {age}{determine_ordinal(age)} birthday, {name}!\nhttps://imgur.com/a/G3wEPyg'
            await channel.send(wish_string)
    birthday_list.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Is your "birthday_list" a file or a normal list? If it is a file, you can't really use a "for each" loop before reading the lines themselves. I would go with:

```
list_of_lines = birthdaylist.readlines()
for each in list_of_lines:
    string = each.rstrip() //remove newline character
    rest of your code
```

make sure to use the readlines with the S to get the whole file in a list and not just one line

Comment: There's no reason to call `readlines` at all. `for each in birthday_list` is fine; it's the *additional* call to `readline` that causes the problem.